# Microsoft Management Console has stopped working

Tags: windows-10, mmc, snap-in

I'm trying to add snap into Microsoft Management Console in windows 10. But when I try to add certificate, an error message is coming with the header **Microsoft Management Console has stopped working**:

[image]

When I click the Debug button, Visual Studio 2015 gives me a message like this:

[image]

I've tried a [solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/my-microsoft-management-console-has-stopped/3c6c8cc7-1850-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1) found by google search saying to run **sfc/scannow** command in command promt but didn't get any result.

Comment: What did you want to use the certificate snap-in for? I wanted to get to the local computer certificates but was having the same problem, then I found a workaround: you can open the local computer certificates directly by running 'certlm.msc' in command prompt

Comment: @Derfenestrator I'm trying to import a external certificate to my local computer. can you give an answer with some more details about how you did it? it might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this doesn't address the error itself, but if you were trying to use the snap-in to access the local computer certificate store then there is a work around.

Open up command prompt and type in 'certlm.msc', this should directly open up the local computer certificate store plug-in without having to go through the buggy menus.

Comment: I think this answer should be accepted, as it exactly solves the problem; you can import certificates to local computer. 
Thanks! You saved my day!